# About const_cast usage in cppreference

Tags: c++

Please refer to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) and go down to the Example.
This is a demonstration about usage of

```
struct type {
    type() :i(3) {}
    void m1(int v) const {
      // this->i = v;                 // compile error: this is a pointer to    const
      const_cast<type*>(this)->i = v; // OK as long as the type object isn't const
  }
   int i;
};
```

**const** here means that m1 could not modify type's member variables. I can't understand why const_cast modify the constness of **this**. I mean, **this** pointer points to current type object, not the i itself.

Why not:

```
const_cast<int>((this)->i) = v;
```

May I say when one of member function use a **const** qualifier, the whole object and all member variables become **const**? Why **this** is const pointer?

Comment: Although you can use a const_cast (as per Storyteller's answer), I suggest that you change m1 to be non-const, `void m1(int v) {...`.  By declaring the method const, you are making a contractual statement that the method does not modify the state of the object.  Having your code const correct is important (well, I think so; some eschew const correctness entirely), and violating the contractual statement can lead to unpleasant late night debugging sessions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't understand why const_cast modify the constness of this

It doesn't. You could say it creates another temporary pointer, which is not a pointer to a `const type`, but contains the same address as `this`. It then uses that pointer to access `i`.

> Why not `const_cast<int>((this)->i)`

You could do something like this, but you need a cast to a reference, not a plain integer.

```
const_cast<int&>(i) = v; // this-> omitted for brevity
```

Same caveats apply as any modification of `i` if `this` points at an object that is *really* const.

> May I say when one of member function use a const modifier, the whole object and all member variables become const? Why this is const pointer?

Yes. The const qualifier on the member function means that `this`'s pointee type is `type const`. And all members (which are not mutable) are also const for any access via `this`.

Comment: For const_cast<newtype>(expr), should newtype always be a reference if not a pointer?

Comment: @wason - You use const_cast to create pointer or reference. As a matter of fact, only casting pointers will create temporaries. You can't do a `const_cast<int>`, it's not a permitted cast. So it's a no-starter to even try.

Comment: @wason - Which I can say in a TL;DR version. Yes

Comment: OK. When I use const_cast<int> I got an error message saying type in const_cast should be pointer, reference or pointer to member to an object type.

Comment: @wason - `const_cast<int>(x)`, if allowed, would give you a non-const copy of `x`. You can already do that by `int y = x;`.